# Does function from argument get captured in closure?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to clear my code form memory leaks and I am not sure in some situations. I am adding capture lists to all my closures to make them stop capturing and making retain cycles, but not sure about functions passed to closure form arguments... onInternetFailed gets to closure and gets strongly captured.

Situation like this:

```
public func send<Data>(_ operation: CSOperation<Data>, _ title: String, _ isProgress: Bool,
                       _ canCancel: Bool, _ isFailedDialog: Bool, _ onInternetFailed: (() -> Void)?,
                       _ onSuccess: ((Data) -> Void)?) -> CSOperation<Data> {
    let process = operation.send(listenOnFailed: false).process!
    if isProgress {
        let cancelAction = canCancel ? CSDialogAction(title: .cs_dialog_cancel) { [unowned operation] in
            operation.cancel()
        } : nil
        let progress = show(progress: title, cancel: cancelAction)
        process.onDone { [unowned progress] _ in progress.hideDialog() }
    }
    //TODO : does function get captured strongly in closure ?
    process.onFailed { [unowned self, unowned operation] failed in
        onProcessFailed(operation, failed, title, isProgress, isFailedDialog, onInternetFailed, onSuccess)
    }
    onSuccess.notNil { [unowned process] in process.onSuccess($0) }
    return operation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Closures (functions) have reference semantics and will always be captured strongly. In fact, you cannot change the capture mode to weak or unowned. If you think about it, it wouldn't make sense either.

When you deal with completion handlers, the best practice you can follow is to ensure that the completion handlers will be called eventually. This ensures, the closure is released (actually the objects it references).

It's a common programmer error to forget to call a completion handler, or to call it twice. A *completion* handler must be called *once* (eventually) and *only* once. For example, check CSOperation if it actually calls either `onFailed` or `onSuccess` when the task completes, when it bails out early, or in any other possible case.

**Update**

When analysing your code, the object `operation` returns an object `process` (presumably holding a strong reference itself).

This process value has a closure value `onFailed` which will be assigned a closure which imports unowned `self`, unowned `operation` and two other closures `onInternetFailed` and `onSuccess`.

(I omit the other details).

When you now look at it, it's the value `operation` that is responsible to hold everything together.

Note also, that there is nowhere a "completion handler" pattern *). Instead, your handlers are kept in instance variables. If these get called, they remain allocated.

So, even if your operation completes, and calls `onFailed` *eventually* - nothing gets deallocated.

It's your responsibility to set the "completion handlers" to `nil` after they have been called. Alternatively, set `process` to `nil`, alternatively set `operation` to `nil.

IMHO, the design should be made more simple and more easy to comprehend.

What I do generally, is to avoid storing "completion" handlers in instance variables. This opens a host of potential errors (due to reference cycles) which you cannot avoid in the code itself, but must be avoided by the caller by enforcing a convention and following strict rules which you have to document, which in turn leads to "leaking implementation details", ...

But you can alleviate the problems by ensuring your "completion handler" will be set to nil once it has been called.

Even, better avoid storing completion handlers in instance variables and apply the "completion handler pattern".

**Completion handler pattern**

The handler will not be stored in an object as an instance variable:

```
    func doWorkAsync(completion: @escaping (Result) -> Void) {
        self.workerQueue.async { 
            // work 
            completion(result)  
        }
    }
```

"Operation Style" variant which clears the completion handler after completion:

```
class MyOperation {
    var completion: ((Result) -> Void)?

    init(completion: (Result) -> Void) {
        self.completion = completion 
    }

    func start() {
        assert(self.completion != nil)
        doWorkAsync { result in 
            let completion = self.completion
            self.completion = nil
            completion?(result)             
        }
     }
}
```

Note that - in certain perspective - a Closure is nothing else than an Operation, and an operation can be represented as a Closure. In other words, it's possible to refactor code using Operations and replace it with pure Closures, thus avoiding any issues stemming from using Operations.

Comment: Ok so functions get captured strongly but what is important is if they reference other object strongly no ? I don't get what you say about calling them once as obviously onInternetFailed is not completion handler and will mostly never be called. But I get that functions are capture in other function strongly and so I should just focus on how they capture other objects.

Comment: A closure is an Object (a reference type) to a tuple of the code for the function and an (optionally) "context".  For escaping closures, the context is allocated on the heap and may have copies  of other references (either weak, strong, unowned) or copies of other const values, or references to var values. The context will be created when the closure is defined and it will be deallocated after the closure has been called and finished and the last reference is gone. Any closure gets deallocated, when the last strong reference ceases to exists as for any other object.